# JWT Token Decode SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to Decode my JWT Token and get that informations for displaying in my View. The problem is  when I print my Jwt Token i can see user data but when i create instance from my jwt token model I can't get data its not displaying  anything.Where do I mistake any idea ?

This JWT Token decode and Model

```
struct Token : Decodable {
    
    let jwtString : String = ApplicationVariables.token
    
    func getJwtToken(){
        do {
            
            let newJWT = try JWT<MyJWTClaims>(jwtString: jwtString)
            
            print("JWT TOKEN İS : \(newJWT.claims.data?.first_name)")
            
        } catch {
            
            print("ERROR!")
            
        }
    }
}

class MyJWTClaims : Claims,ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data : JWTData?
    
}

class JWTData : ObservableObject,Codable {
    
    @Published var first_name : String?
    @Published var last_name : String?
    @Published var email : String?
    @Published var user_verified : Bool?
   
}
```

And this is where I trying to show JwtToken data ;

```
struct ProfileTopView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var jwtTokenData = MyJWTClaims()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 69"))
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15, alignment: .center)
            
            Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Vector-8"))
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.22, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.10, alignment: .center)
                .offset(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.048)
            
            Text(jwtTokenData.data?.first_name ?? "Test")
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .bold()
                .offset(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.14)
            
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no code that would extract the user attributes from the token and put them into the *JWTData* instance. Did you forget that code, or is your question how that part would be achieved?

Comment: What is the use of “Token” struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return back `JWTData` instance populated with **decoded** result. In below code I am directly returning initialised object, you have to first decode as you are already doing, and populate the values.

```
import SwiftUI

protocol Token {
    func getJwtToken() -> JWTData
    var jwtString:String{get set}
}

class TokenDecoder : Token {
    var jwtString: String = "myToken"
    var jwtObj:JWTData?
    
    func getJwtToken() -> JWTData{
        // Perform JWTdecoding and return object
        JWTData(first_name:"foo",last_name:"bar",email:"abc@xyz.com",user_verified:false)
    }
}

class MyJWTClaims : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data : JWTData?
    
    init(decoder:Token) {
        self.data = decoder.getJwtToken()
    }
    
}

struct JWTData:Decodable  {
    
    var first_name : String?
    var last_name : String?
    var email : String?
    var user_verified : Bool?
    
}

struct ProfileTopView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var jwtTokenData = MyJWTClaims(decoder: TokenDecoder())
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            Image("CDF")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15, alignment: .center)
            
            Image("Home")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.22, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.10, alignment: .center)
                .offset(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.048)
            
            Text(jwtTokenData.data?.first_name ?? "Test")
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .bold()
                .offset(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.14)
            
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```